# How do i get a list of all the latitudes and longitudes from a database within a specific area?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, query-optimization, where-clause

I have a table in a Postgres DB containing places and their corresponding latitude and longitude values.

```
Places (id, name, lat, lng)  # primary-key(id)
```

I will get an input of a pair of latitudes and longitudes forming a rectangle.

```
{
  "long_ne": 12.34, 
  "lat_ne": 34.45, 
  "long_sw": 15.34, 
  "lat_sw": 35.56
}
```

I want to get all the rows that *fall* inside the rectangle.

The rows can't be sorted based on their lat-lng values as that will cause trouble while inserting new values.

What would be the best way to go about solving this to optimize queries to get the result?

I can obviously do it using the `WHERE` clause, but would it be the ost optimized solution? There would be a massive number of rows in the table and is there a way this query can be optimized to speed up the result?

Comment: Have a look at Postgis. The simple coordinate comparison will fail miserably should the bounding box cover the antimeridian.

Comment: Also with large bounding box, you may want to use great circles instead of straight lines

Answer (score 0):

It this what you want?

```
select *
from places
where 
    lat between :lat_no and :lat_sw
    and lng between :long_no and :long_sw
```

Where `:lat_no`, `:lat_ws` `:long_no` and `:long_sw` are the input parameters to the query.

This gives you all rows whose latitude and longitude fall between the square boundaries. Note that `between` considers the inteval inclusive of their bounds on both ends. You can change this as needed with inequality conditions, for example, this makes the match inclusive on the lower bound and exclusive on the upper bound:

```
where
    lat >= :lat_no and lat < :lat_sw
    and lng >= :long_no and lng < :long_sw
```

Answer (score 0):

Won't a simple SQL query suffice here?

```
SELECT *
FROM Places
WHERE   (lat > lat_sw) 
    AND (long > long_sw)
    AND (lat < lat_ne)
    AND (long < long_ne)
```